# Is there a way to disable AMDPlugin?

Tags: webpack

Webpack includes AMDPlugin by default, so if a module checks for AMD before CommonJS, that module definition will be used.

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
  define([], factory)
} else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
  exports.foo = factory();
}
```

I would like to ignore AMD altogether. Is there a way to do it in webpack?

Comment: The solution: 
`module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js/, loader: 'imports?define=>false'}
    ]
  }`

Comment: Sometimes the AMD definitions just lack some directory structures. In that case you can add the missing path to `resolve: { fallback: [ ... ] }` and let webpack resolve them. No extra loader needed.

Comment: @WiktorKozlik please, add your solution as an actual solution so it is easier to see it.

Answer (score 20):

It can be solved with [imports-loader](https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader#disable-amd)

> There are many modules that check for a define function before using CommonJS. Since webpack is capable of both, they default to AMD in this case, which can be a problem if the implementation is quirky.
>   Then you can easily disable the AMD path by writing

`imports?define=>false`

Simply do

```
require('imports?define=>false!myjsfile.js')
```

**OR**
a better approach is in webpack.config.js you add a loader

```
loaders: [ { test: /myjsfile.js/, loader: 'imports?define=>false'} ]
```

Comment: How to do that when you have multiple files (four to be exact) and one of them have to be loaded before the other 3, cause they depend on it

Comment: @codepreneur simply require them in the correct order.
require('imports?define=>false!file1.js');
require('imports?define=>false!file2.js');
require('imports?define=>false!file3.js');

Comment: I did and it didn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488225/how-to-disable-amd-on-4-files-and-load-them-in-order-with-webpack?noredirect=1#comment70182681_41488225

Comment: `Query arguments on 'loader' has been removed in favor of the 'options' property`

Answer (score 4):

You can also add to the following to your rules to disable AMD(webpack 2+):

```
module: {
    rules: [
        { parser: { amd: false } }
    ]
}
```

From: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/

Comment: I'm getting `Json Modules Plugin does not match the API schema.
 - parser has an unknown property 'amd'. These properties are valid:
   object { parse? }`. Could webpack API have changed?

Comment: It seems to require `test: /\.js$/`, besides the `parser` parameter in my case, guessing because allowed fields depend on file type.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider [`script-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/script-loader/), as mentioned at the end of the [Shimming documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#other-utilities):

> The **script-loader** evaluates code in the global context, similar to
>   inclusion via a script tag. In this mode, every normal library should
>   work. *require, module, etc. are undefined*.