# How to disable AMD on 4 files and load them in order with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, requirejs, amd

I need to disable AMD on 4 files and load `video.js` first before loading the other 3 files, because they depend on it. When I tried doing it in webpack.config.js like so:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: './src',
    port: 3333
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules|lib/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2'],
          plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /[\/\\]lib[\/\\](video|playlist|vpaid|overlay)\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules|src/
        loader: 'imports?define=>false'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It doesn't really work, because it just loads `video.js` (with disabled AMD) and completely ignores the other 3 files.

My folder structure is like so:

```
▾ lib/
    overlay.js
    playlist.js
    video.js
    vpaid.js
▸ node_modules/
▾ public/
    200.html
    bundle.js
▾ src/
    App.js
    index.html
    main.js
  LICENSE
  package.json
  README.md
  webpack.config.js
```

Now, I found something that takes me 1 step back, because now even `video.js` doesn't load:

```
require('imports?define=>false!../lib/video.js')
require('imports?define=>false!../lib/playlist.js')
require('imports?define=>false!../lib/vpaid.js')
require('imports?define=>false!../lib/overlay.js')
```

and instead just throws these kinds of warnings:

```
WARNING in ./~/imports-loader?define=>false!./lib/video.js
Critical dependencies:
15:415-422 This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better results.
 @ ./~/imports-loader?define=>false!./lib/video.js 15:415-422

WARNING in ./~/imports-loader?define=>false!./lib/playlist.js
Critical dependencies:
10:417-424 This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better results.
 @ ./~/imports-loader?define=>false!./lib/playlist.js 10:417-424

WARNING in ./~/imports-loader?define=>false!./lib/vpaid.js
Critical dependencies:
4:113-120 This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better results.
 @ ./~/imports-loader?define=>false!./lib/vpaid.js 4:113-120

WARNING in ./~/imports-loader?define=>false!./lib/overlay.js
Critical dependencies:
10:416-423 This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better results.
 @ ./~/imports-loader?define=>false!./lib/overlay.js 10:416-423
```

So, my question is, how can I make this work in `webpack.config.js` so that I don't get these warnings?

Comment: Showing us your folder structure and the way you require those files could be helpful as well.

Comment: done. so how can I solve my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem! To make this work you need this:

```
 {
    test: /[\/\\]lib[\/\\](video|playlist|vpaid|overlay)\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules|src/
    loader: 'imports?define=>false'
  }
```

and this

```
require('script-loader!../lib/video.js')
require('script-loader!../lib/playlist.js')
require('script-loader!../lib/vpaid.js')
require('script-loader!../lib/overlay.js')
```

together!

Now, if you use this (instead of script-loader):

```
require('imports?define=>false!../lib/video.js')
require('imports?define=>false!../lib/playlist.js')
require('imports?define=>false!../lib/vpaid.js')
require('imports?define=>false!../lib/overlay.js')
```

It's not gonna work! (you need both imports-loader and script-loader working in unison.