# Backbone sandbox without iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, backbone.js, webpack, ecmascript-6

I wrote a small ES6 script and complied it with babel using webpack (UMD target). I want Backbone (and Underscore) to be bundled into the script so users don't have to import it too.

```
// src/index.js
import Backbone from 'backbone';
(function(){
    return Backbone.VERSION;
})
```

Unfortunately, when the compiled script is imported into an HTML file, Backbone is also imported into the global scope. This can cause all sort of issues when the script is imported into a page that uses a different version of BB for example.

```
<script src="/script.min.js"></script>
<script>
    console.log(Backbone.VERSION); // Backbone is defined :(
</script>
```

I know a solution is to execute the script inside an iframe. Is there any other way to completely isolate this BB script effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior is because of [this line in backbone.js](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/0eca92f441f63091f3cab0fc900fa21afbfc55fe/backbone.js#L18) so there are two options for your, either

- Do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302742/is-there-a-way-to-disable-amdplugin) to stop Webpack from processing AMD defines inside Backbone, which will make it fall back to CommonJS, which does not set a global.
- Use [`.noConflict()`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/0eca92f441f63091f3cab0fc900fa21afbfc55fe/backbone.js#L53) to clear the unexpected global, e.g.

  ```
  import Backbone from "backbone";
  Backbone.noConflict();
  ```